# Can't find novel.cls file

Tags: packages

I am writing a novel and fairly new to using LaTeX.  Please bare with me if this is a silly question.  I am working off of the novel demo LaTeX file using the TexWorks software.  I have inserted my words into the file.  When I run the LaTeX code, I get the error message saying "! LaTeX Error: File `novel.cls' not found."

Do I need to download this file from somewhere?  If so, where can I get it?

Comment: The `novel.cls` is a 'package' on TeXLive, MikTeX and must be on CTAN as well, here is a link to its documention:[novel](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/luatex/latex/novel/doc/novel.pdf)

Comment: Welcome to LaTeX! [Welcome to TeX.SX!](//meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](//meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: The `novel.cls` is the document class  (.cls) that you are trying to use. This file set the predefined layout and available commands. For instance, `\chapter{}` works using `book.cls`  but is not defined in `article.cls`. The better is install the whole `novel` package with the administrative tool of your  TeXLive/MikTeX distribution, but also works download only  `novel.cls` in your working directory (where is `yourfile.tex`). Said that, I suggest stay  with `\documentclass{article} \begin{document} Hi! \end{document}` until you know what are you doing.

Comment: Observation: Download a  `.cls`  in the working directory works only if the class file is not dependent of another lacking files. This class require many others packages and style files (`.sty`).

Comment: I was trying to execute the example novel from the novel package.  Should I copy the code here?  Again, I am sorry.  I am such a newbie at this.

Answer (score 1):

I am the author of the novel document class.

Due to some change in one or more other LaTeX packages, novel now crashes. This behavior is as of the last couple of weeks. Novel certainly did not crash prior to that. The crash is fundamental, in that the user's document content does not matter. It is not due to any change in novel.

My own archive compiles with older TeX code (as of a month ago), but does not compile with current TeX code. Thus, the problem is with the other TeX code.

Since I introduced novel, twice I have had to revise code, to compensate for changes in another package. This time, no. It seems that the package(s) causing the crash are not necessary for novel's purpose, but they are automatically loaded whether novel likes it or not; then novel crashes.

I have requested that CTAN remove novel. Sorry about that, but I do not have the tme or inclination to chase this.

It may be that some users will find that novel compiles, only to discover that it fails after TeX update.

Comment: Do you still have the github repo active? The cause might be easy to spot and fix for somebody else.

Comment: @Johannes_B GitHub gone. The problem was not in new code. Rather, my existing stable known-good code, with known-good documents, now fails. Messages indicate problems in TeX. This package is directed toward writers, not programmers. I cannot ask writers to deal with something that abruptly fails, for no apparent reason, every month or so.

Answer (score 1):

Again, I am the author of the novel package (but my prior username is obsolete).

Due to popular(?) demand, I have located a minor bug in the docs, and a major bug in the code that will affect some users.

Although I will not continuously maintain the package, I did it this time. Look for version 1.3, appearing soon.

Comment: Me, the author again... Now in version 1.80. Works. The `novel` class requires a lot of support from other packages. Once in a while, it stumbles for that reason. But things have settled down.